# Is it possible to load some requirejs "module"s later?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've configured my project with multiple requirejs modules, I would like to know how to load some of them only when needed (for example the map-related module to be loaded only when user opens a maps panel)

Comment: Yes of course, why not…

Comment: As it is your question does not show any code. We therefore don't know what you're having a problem with exactly. Is it the language, the logic, the libraries, ... Therefore this question invites answers that will focus on whatever part the answerer feels to focus on, and will probably miss what your problem actually is. Please add your code so that we know where you are coming from.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a how-to question. As far as I know '<script data-main="js/blabla" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>' loads all dependencies at once. I want to know how to postpone the loading of certain modules.

Comment: This may be helpful: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy/)

Answer (score 0):

One simple example would be to check if the element exists in the markup and only load and execute further modules if they are really required.

```
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll( '.slider' );   // find any element with class .slider
if( sliders.length > 0 ) {                              // check if there is aleast one
    require( ['jquery', 'view/bootstrap-slider'], function( jQuery ) {  // load jQuery and the Twitter Bootstrap component for sliders
        jQuery( sliders ).slider();                     // setup the Twitter Bootstrap slider
    } );
}
```

A drawback to this approach is that it does not re-run for markup that is inserted dynamically using AJAX.

You may use some sort of [selector listener](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/05/introducing-live-extensions-better-dom-javascript/) to also handle dynamic markup changes.

```
require( [ 'better-dom' ], function( DOM ) {            // include chemerisuk/better-dom

    DOM.extend( '.slider', {                            // setup a “live extension/selector listener” for elements with the class .slider
        constructor: function() {
            var sliderElement = this._node;
            require( [ 'view/bootstrap-slider' ], function( Slider ) {
                jQuery( sliderElement ).slider();       // setup the Twitter Bootstrap slider
            } );
        }
    } );

} );
```

This example uses the selector listeners through the [better-dom](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dom) “live extensions”. Every time an element with the given selector gets added to the current document, an event will be fired and anything inside the constructor is executed once for each added element. This is helpful when loading whole pages via AJAX (“page transitions”) or otherwise adding content dynamically.